# Hyper-V and BIOS Virtualization enabled cause Windows 8 to hang on boot

Tags: windows-8, bios, virtualization, hyper-v

When I enable both Hyper-V and hardware virtualization in BIOS, Windows 8 hangs after POSTing. It sits at the Windows logo indefinitely, but disabling either Virtualization in the BIOS or Hyper-V in Windows solves the problem. According to CoreInfo, my processor supports it.

I'm running:

- Windows 8 Professional 64-bit
- AMD Athlon X3 450
- Gigabyte MA-770-DS3 (rev 2.0) (link here:
  http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=2874#sp)

All signs seem to point to the two being able to play nicely together, but reality seems to disagree. Assuming I have the latest BIOS version, does anybody know if there might be some other problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! Turns out I just needed to update my BIOS. I'd done so a few months ago, but I must not have grabbed the absolute latest version because they were labeled as "Beta drivers". 
If anybody else is having this issue, visit [Gigabyte's page](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=2874#bios) for the motherboard, and download the FDE BIOS. Updating to that version and enabling Virtualization in BIOS setup worked like a charm.